# Fix frame orientation using Google Mobile Vision

Tags: ios, swift, uiimage, google-ios-vision

I'm using [Google Mobile Vision](https://developers.google.com/vision/ios/reference/) to process camera frames and detect faces. After detecting a face I want to save the frame to a file but it has a wrong orientation.

```
func captureOutput(_ captureOutput: AVCaptureOutput!, didOutputSampleBuffer sampleBuffer: CMSampleBuffer!, from connection: AVCaptureConnection!) {
    guard let image = GMVUtility.sampleBufferTo32RGBA(sampleBuffer) else {
        print("No Image")
        return
    }

    // wrong orientation when saving image here
}
```

Comment: How you solved it ??

Comment: @ChanchalWarde, it is not solved yet.